# Created by field in SharePoint online search shows the name of the person who modified it

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, sharepoint-search

SharePoint online search is showing the name of the person who modified the document rather then who created it when I use the CreatedBy managed property.

I have got two questions:

1. how can I show only the created by value and not modified by in search?
2. what does Office:4 mean as a crawled property?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ctx.CurrentItem.DisplayAuthor
```

to get the name of Created By Field

Comment: I see that DisplayAuthor is not mapped to any crawled properties in the Search schema. I will give it a try.